# Как правильно настроить preg_replace?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Сайт на Dle, есть такая регулярка:

```
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'text-align:right;'si", "righttt", $row['full_story'] );
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'text-align:left;'si", "lefttt", $row['full_story'] );
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'text-align:center;'si", "centerrr", $row['full_story'] );
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'<img'si", "<amp-img layout=\"responsive\" width=\"1080\" height=\"610\"", $row['full_story'] );
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'<!--dle_image_end-->'si", "</amp-img>", $row['full_story'] );
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'<iframe'si", "<amp-iframe layout=\"responsive\" sandbox=\"allow-scripts allow-same-origin allow-popups\"", $row['full_story'] );
$row['full_story'] = preg_replace( "'</iframe>'si", "</amp-iframe>", $row['full_story'] );
```

Но она работает неправильно. После первой замены она удаляет остальную часть текста, в чем ошибка?

Comment: Почитайте что такое ограничивающий символ в регулярном выражении и что такое экранирование мета-символов.

Comment: @Slaxor Покажите значения $row['full_story'] до выполнения указанного кода, затем после каждой строчки, вплоть до строчки после которой происходит **ошибка**